# Use a Type Alias with a generic type in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, type-alias

Currently I use this type alias

```kotlin
typealias GridMatrix = MutableList<CoordsValue, String?>
```

Now I want to replace `String?` with `T?` because of reason I wanted to do this

```kotlin
typealias GridMatrix = MutableList<CoordsValue, T?>
```

Unfortunately the compiler does not allow it and therefore I am a bit sad since I liked my typealias here and am using it throughout the codebase.

Is there a way to maybe get this to work somewhat? Workaround or whatever? Also I don't understand **why** it is not working? I thought of a `typealias` just as a simple placeholder or replacment like in C++ `DEFINE` which just replaces the stuff before the real compilation starts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare a typealias with type arguments.

Try this:

```kotlin
typealias GridMatrix<T> = MutableList<CoordsValue, T?>
```

Here's the [kotlin reference on typealiases](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html).